# How can i stop IE hanging whilst loading Facebook Social plug in (Like box) on my site?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have implemented the Facebook like button on my site by using the asynchronous JS SDK and it's working great! However it takes a long time to load, which is not a great problem (Would be nicer if it loader quicker though..) as the rest of the page loads fine.

However, if your view the the site in any version of IE the whole page is unresponsive until Facebook Like / comments have loaded... All the images and other scripts are loaded, but the whole page is locked.

Any ideas on how i can rectify this for IE users?

I have seen this post: [How do I keep the Facebook like button from delaying the loading on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882328/how-do-i-keep-the-facebook-like-button-from-delaying-the-loading-on-my-website) but this was solved by using the Async version, where as mine IS using this and still hanging?

If it helps I can post a link to my site / page that it appears on?

Comment: of course it'll help if you post a link to your page!

Comment: Thanks - Okay it's an e-commerce store and it's any of the product pages, so this one for example: http://www.guitarfood.com/strings/martin-6-string-bronze-custom-light-011-052.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, IE was hanging because I had a CSS3 transform on my images and apparently this slows down IE (Even though it cannot render the transform. So i can disable by this via conditional comments in the CSS or in my case modernizr.

Answer (score 2):

Well, my only advice here is to place your FB JS code just before the `</body>` tag. But I have other "tips" for your site in general.

1. Try to minify/combine your CSS and JS files when possible
2. Try moving your JS code to the body tag (at the end)
3. Do you really need the Prototype AND jQuery libraries?! try removing one of them and port the functionality to the other (*almost* all tasks can be done with either library)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments - i would love to do all of those, however this is a magento site and boy does magento like JS! It also freaks if you move too many of its scripts to the bottom (I'm trying it one by on at the moment to see where it breaks.)